# How to make return wait until calculation is complete

Tags: swift, csv, asynchronous, return, dropbox

thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to download the data from a CSV within my Dropbox. I am able to download the data successfully, but right now I'm trying to enclose/create functions out of these processes. Namely, I want create a function where I download the CSV and return the data as a string.

My issue is this though: My function returns the data variable before the download from Dropbox is complete. Therefore it doesn't return anything. i.e., I'll see the comment "returned allData variable" first, then "converted to allData variable" next. I need to reverse that somehow.

I see 2 options: 1) Figure out how to work this asynchronous bit (I'm new to Swift and have been scouring all over online to get a better understanding of it), or 2) somehow structure the `return` call to only execute after the data has fully downloaded.

Do you guys have any suggestions for how to move forward? I've included my code below.

```
func downloadFile () -> [[String:String]] {

var allData = [[String:String]]()

if let client = Dropbox.authorizedClient {

    let destination : (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> NSURL = { temporaryURL, response in

        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]

        // generate a unique name for this file in case we've seen it before

        let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString

        let pathComponent = "\(UUID)-\(response.suggestedFilename!)"

        print ("The path component is \(pathComponent)")

        return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)

    }

//Option 1: Create some bit of asynchronous code here?
    client.files.download(path: "/Master Test.csv", destination: destination).response { response, error in

        if let (metadata, url) = response {

            print("*** Download file ***")

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            let dlString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let a = CSwiftV(String: String(dlString!))

            allData = a.keyedRows!

            print ("converted to allData variable")

//Option 2: Somehow embed the return call here?

        } else {

            print (error!)

        }
    }
}

print ("returned allData variable")

return allData

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend adding a `completionHandler` to your function. You can learn more about closures in the swift docs. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

```
func downloadFile (completion: (data: [[String:String]]?, error: NSError?) -> ()) -> (){

var allData = [[String:String]]()

if let client = Dropbox.authorizedClient {

    let destination : (NSURL, NSHTTPURLResponse) -> NSURL = { temporaryURL, response in

        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]

        // generate a unique name for this file in case we've seen it before

        let UUID = NSUUID().UUIDString

        let pathComponent = "\(UUID)-\(response.suggestedFilename!)"

        print ("The path component is \(pathComponent)")

        return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)

    }

//Option 1: Create some bit of asynchronous code here?
    client.files.download(path: "/Master Test.csv", destination: destination).response { response, error in

        if let (metadata, url) = response {

            print("*** Download file ***")

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
            let dlString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let a = CSwiftV(String: String(dlString!))

            allData = a.keyedRows!

            print ("converted to allData variable")

//Option 2: Somehow embed the return call here?
            completion(data: allData, error: nil)

        } else {

            print (error!)
            completion(data: nil, error: error)

        }
    }
}

print ("returned allData variable")

return allData

}
```

Function call

```
 downloadFile(){
  //start your loader here
            dropboxData in
           //remove here
            if(dropboxData.error == nil){
                print(dropboxData.data)
            }else{
                print(dropboxData.error)
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. Still trying to figure out what is going on - might need to brush up on closures.

Comment: @ChingJuiYoung No problem. Closures are quit simple to use and understand, it just takes some practice (like all things). I highly recommend looking at the documentation link and searching google (there are many good tutorials/blog posts explaining how closures work and how to use them.)